# How to create a user using ecto and phoenix v1.3

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a phoenix / phx v1.3 project that I have been working on, and have run into a issue trying to create a user using an `iex` session.  As far as I can tell the code that I have written should be working because the app compiles.

I ran the below generator to setup a `schema` for user accounts.

```
mix phx.gen.json Accounts User users email:string encrypted_password:string username:string
```

I then followed through a couple of tutorials on how to setup the schema to accept the creation of user accounts by modifying,

```
/lib/kegcopr_api/accounts/user.ex
```

**user.ex**

```
defmodule KegCopRAPI.Accounts.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  # import Ecto
  import Ecto.Changeset
  # import Ecto.Query

  schema "accounts_users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :encrypted_password, :string
    field :username, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true

    timestamps()
  end

  @required_fields ~w(email username)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(struct, params \\ :empty) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> validate_required(@required_fields, @optional_fields)
    # |> cast(params, [:email, :encrypted_password, :username])
    # |> validate_required([:email, :encrypted_password, :username])
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
    |> validate_length(:username, min: 1, max: 20)
    |> update_change(:email, &String.downcase/1)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
    |> update_change(:username, &String.downcase/1)
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
  end

  def registration_changeset(struct, params) do
    struct
    |> changeset(params)
    |> cast(params, ~w(password), [])
    |> validate_required(~w(password), [])
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 6, max: 100) |> put_encrypted_pw
  end

  defp put_encrypted_pw(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: pass}} -> put_change(changeset, :encrypted_password, Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(pass))
    _ ->
      changeset
    end
  end
end
```

I then run `iex -S mix` to start an interactive elixir session for the app, and I try to insert a user into the DB with the below command,

```
changeset = KegCopRAPI.Accounts.User.registration_changeset(%KegCopRAPI.Accounts.User{}, %{email: "first@example.com", username: "first", password: "password"})
```

However, the above mentioned command is giving me the below error,

```
warning: `Ecto.Changeset.cast/4` is deprecated, please use `cast/3` + `validate_required/3` instead
    (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/accounts/user.ex:21: KegCopRAPI.Accounts.User.changeset/2
    (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/accounts/user.ex:35: KegCopRAPI.Accounts.User.registration_changeset/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:438: :erl_eval.expr/5
    (elixir) src/elixir.erl:224: :elixir.erl_eval/3
    (elixir) src/elixir.erl:212: :elixir.eval_forms/4
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:182: IEx.Evaluator.handle_eval/6
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:175: IEx.Evaluator.do_eval/4
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:155: IEx.Evaluator.eval/4
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:61: IEx.Evaluator.loop/3
    (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:21: IEx.Evaluator.init/4
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3

** (ArgumentError) unknown field "email" for changeset on %KegCopRAPI.Accounts.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "accounts_users">, email: nil, encrypted_password: nil, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, password: nil, updated_at: nil, username: nil}
           (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:1318: Ecto.Changeset.ensure_field_exists!/2
           (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:1305: anonymous fn/5 in Ecto.Changeset.validate_required/3
         (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1755: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
           (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:1304: Ecto.Changeset.validate_required/3
    (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/accounts/user.ex:22: KegCopRAPI.Accounts.User.changeset/2
    (kegcopr_api) lib/kegcopr_api/accounts/user.ex:35: KegCopRAPI.Accounts.User.registration_changeset/2
```

Any help on how I can create a user would greatly be appreciated.  Presently, I'm not sure if the error is in the iex changeset command I am inputting or within the `user.ex` file.

Comment: Try sending the field list as a list of atoms: `~w(password)` -> `~w(password)a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a list of strings to `validate_required`, however it must be a list of atoms. `cast` can take either. So, change all your `~w(...)` to `~w(...)a` and it should work. I would also remove the deprecated APIs.

```
  @required_fields ~w(email username)a
  @all_fields ~w()a ++ @required_fields

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, @all_fields)
    |> validate_required(@required_fields)
    # |> cast(params, [:email, :encrypted_password, :username])
    # |> validate_required([:email, :encrypted_password, :username])
    |> validate_format(:email, ~r/@/)
    |> validate_length(:username, min: 1, max: 20)
    |> update_change(:email, &String.downcase/1)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
    |> update_change(:username, &String.downcase/1)
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
  end

  def registration_changeset(struct, params) do
    struct
    |> changeset(params)
    |> cast(params, ~w(password))
    |> validate_required(~w(password)a)
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 6, max: 100) 
    |> put_encrypted_pw
  end
```